# Azure keys for Luis not available

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to publish a staging version of my LUIS app.
I have set up the Cognitive Services App in Azure Australia East and can see the key in the Azure portal.
However in the AU Luis portal https://au.luis.ai , when I go to the publish tab and try to add a key to the Australian Region, I can select my Tenant and my subscription, but there is no key available to select.

I note that the Azure portal does say that it can take 10 minutes for the keys to be available, but I have waited much longer than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have set up the Cognitive Services App in Azure Australia South East

How can you create LUIS service in Australia South East, because it it not supported. And which Cognitive Service App are you created?

I would suggest you to create LUIS service in Australia East and try to add the key in publish page.

The authoring region app can only be published to a corresponding publish region. If your app is currently in the wrong authoring region, export the app, and import it into the correct authoring region for your publishing region.

[image]

**Note:** If you are publishing LUIS app in Australia, you need to set up the LUIS services in Australia East only.

> Notice: It may take up to 10 minutes for the newly (re)generated keys
>   to take effect.

This is for regenerating new keys and not for the existing keys.

Comment: Oops it was Australia East. I have corrected the question.

Comment: I think it took much longer than 10 minutes

Comment: Yes, I have noticed the same, some times it would take longer than 10 minutes to show up in the LUIS publish page.